# Mass DNS Requests from an unknown program. How to identify?

Tags: server, 20.04, dns

I run a PiHole dns server, I keep seeing mass dns requests for the domain mariadb from my Ubuntu Server. About 50,000 a day, 3 A and 3 AAAA every 10 seconds. I can't seem to find a way to identify the program that is sending them. I've tried setting the entry manually to a non existant ip in /etc/hosts and that stopped the requests for a while but then they came back and there was still no way to identify what program was sending them. Looking for a way to identify the program doing this. I've checked configs and temporarily stopped almost every program I can think of and the requests have continued.

UPDATE: These dns requests are showing up in my dns query log on my pihole and occasionally overloading it. This is why I thought pihole relevant, pihole is running on a different machine, and this machine is not running anything to do with dns except the "systemd-resolved stub resolver". Mariadb is running on the server in a docker container for bookstack (Also dockerized), mysql is running on the server (not in docker) for several wordpress sites but there is no configuration in any of these services that should be causing them to lookup the "mariadb" domain. PHP7.4.9 is installed as required for the wordpress sites.

Comment: What DNS requests?   Is this server a DNS server?  Is it running PHP alongside MariaDB?  Are you running MariaDB on your system?  We need more information, and if your system has some type of update checker running on the system, chances are the system or applications are checking for updates.  PiHole DNS server is also offtopic here, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your DNS server, as `root` you can use `tcpdump` to see the actual traffic, and identify the source IPs from which you receive the requests. Something like:

```
tcpdump -vvnn tcp port 53 or udp port 53
```

should show a great deal of output, so you can save this output to a file, and attach part of it here, if you cannot recognize the source IPs..

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I actually know from the logs that the queries are coming from my Ubuntu Server already, just not sure what program is doing it.

Comment: You are `DoS`-ing yourself? `netstat -tanp|grep :53` should give you pointers on which PID from your localhost/127.0.0.1 is generating requests towards the local DNS server.

Comment: Essentially yes that is what's happening. Unfortunately the only response from that is `tcp  0  0 127.0.0.53:53  0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN   882/systemd-resolve` I believe this is because of the systemd dns resolver. I've tried to override that and go direct to the main dns, I've managed to add my dns to the resolv.conf file without it being overwritten but 127.0.0.53 still takes precedence even being 2nd.

Comment: you may want to, to @ron's netstat parameters,  add a "u" udp (or remove the t) and add a "c" for continuous to monitor constantly monitor

Comment: @WU-TANG yes, thank you, I forgot the `-u` for `utp`. Good catch.

Comment: I managed to disable the systemd resolver, but I've been left with more questions than answers. I ran the command `netstat -tuanpc|grep 10.20.1.10:53` as root (My dns is at 10.20.1.10 and was getting alot of unnecessary data with just :53) and left it running for a while. Continued to monitor the dns request logs on my dns server, requests are still being made every 10 seconds, but nothing shows up in the netstat output for the requests. If I understand correctly that shouldn't be possible but yet somehow it's happening. @Ron Thanks again, any other ideas?

Comment: On the machine where you DO NOT want to receive those requests, `tcpdump` is your best friend to identify WHO is sending those packets. If you really see there the local IP, then you can try stopping individual services, just to see if the behavior of `tcpdump` will change. Or you are not reading the `tcpdump` correctly.. and it is not a local SOURCE. Without more info, I do not know which way to go and troubleshoot..

Comment: I think the challenge is how do you see what is making the request to 127.0.0.53. <-- That stub listener is going to make the request on the processes behalf (if i understand correctly). That request may leave the machine or may already be cached. You can try some things like turning off caching in /etc/systemd/resolv.conf... and restarting systemd.resolved.service.. there are other things in that config to play with. `resolvectl flush-caches`. sometimes i got the desired netstat output, most times not. I am no DNS expert. I got different/inconsistent results with various configs of that file.

Comment: I did run tcpdump on the dns server to see that the requests were indeed coming from 10.20.1.4 (Ubuntu Server) and I got the systemd resolver disabled to work directly with the dns server, the dns requests still appear and the netstat command on the Ubuntu server shows nothing even close to that repetitive in requests.Here is a snippet of the tcpdump from the dns server https://pastebin.com/CYYvgQqC

Comment: try : `apt-get install nethogs`... if there is that much traffic maybe it will register there. But with all that you've said and all that I have seen, I suspect it will only register as the systemd-resolved process making the requests. You can try running it on the localhost, but the same with `tcpdump -i lo port 53` (only shows the local host going out to the stub listener), it may only show something similar..... but I don't have all of your traffic, so i cannot test it and say for sure. you could also try `lsof -i :53` or `lsof -i | awk '/UDP/'`.. but i think it will be the same

Comment: @WU-TANG nethogs didn't give me alot of useful data but the tcpdump (on eno1 now that systemd is being bypassed) did give me the output I was looking for but I'm not exactly sure how to read it. https://pastebin.com/KdP1P2wE here's a snippet of that.

Comment: i believe the tcpdump traffic says your dns server 0/0/0 is telling your enterprise-ubuntu.home server that it has no answers/authority/additional records in its response to the maria site request. From enterpriseXXX, Can you `tail -f /var/log/syslog` and look for any repeat failures to communicate with the mariadb site. And/Or do the same if you have another place where you are sending mariadb logs. Is this server configured to get updates/and if so from someplace other than the web? Does this network and all of it's components have access to the internet?

Comment: Nothing I can see the file is 25,000 lines but a search for "mariadb" came up with nothing. I checked for mariadb anywhere in the log directory all I got is this `./syslog.1:324689:Aug 15 22:43:26 enterprise systemd-resolved[915]: /etc/hosts:3: address 'mariadb' is invalid, ignoring: Invalid argument` I believe this is simply saying that the address assigned to mariadb in /etc/hosts was invalid (It was as I was just trying to stop the requests at that point). That was from yesterdays syslog. I do run several docker containers on the server but tried stopping them all and there was no effect.

Comment: I think I finally found it after 4 days. I found a stray folder that used to contain some docker containers including a mariadb server, turns out that the containers were removed incorrectly and even though the files were gone the containers were still there running and restarting in the background, without config the defaults took over, and when the local system didn't know where mariadb was it asked the dns server. I can't believe it took me that long to remember the docker ps command (I run everything in docker compose in a few folders). Thank You all for your help!

Comment: @Jacob... and days after that... I stumbled into the man pages looking for something else... i linked /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf to /etc/resolv.conf... and started getting closer to the results we wanted with the netstat. From what I can tell, that is supposed to send the request directly to the dns providers. I went further and cleared the caches and even disabled systemd-resolved.service... More times than not, when I pinged a random imaginary hostname, it appeared in the netstat output with the "ping" being the process. `man systemd-resolved.service` shows the 4 modes of operation.